# USB ports not recognizing devices (vista)

Tags: windows-vista, usb

I'm trying to fix a problem on a Vista machine where all the USB ports seem to have power but they don't recognize devices plugged into them.

It seemed to start after I plugged my mp3 player (sansa clip) into it and disconnect it.  So it sounds similar to this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817900 but that was for XP.  And I did try all the fixes (including the registry entry) but they did not help.

It also sounds similar to this SU question 50110 but I don't think it is the mother board.

I have see other places that suggest reinstalling the OS...but that seems like a last resort type of thing.  I have also seen a suggestion of doing a system restore but not sure if that will help.

Any ideas of what I can try?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work for your case. Goto **Computer Management > System Tools > Device Manager**. Look under the **Universal Serial Bus controllers**; there are a variety of Generic USB Hub and USB Root Hub nodes. Try disabling and re-enabling those nodes.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with Windows XP. My 16 gb usb drive gave a "not recognized" error when hot plugged but worked if I rebooted. Disabling and re-enabling the USB host controller in Device Manager fixed the problem. Thanks icelava.

Answer (score 0):

You could try booting from the Ubuntu Live CD to check if the device registers while in the port. If not, it's likely hardware-related (so restoring or reinstalling Windows would have no effect).